# php build or replace part of regular expression

Tags: php, laravel

I have this regular expression and I want to replace the "lb" part with the parameter that's being passed in with what ever weight they want to use so what I have is this

```
protected function validateCheckWeight($attribute, $value, $parameters) 
{        
    // this always outputs correctly either true or false
    return preg_match('/^(?!0\d|0lb$)\d+(?:\.\d+)?lb$/', $value);
}
```

and what I want is this but it doesn't work when doing validation

```
protected function validateCheckWeight($attribute, $value, $parameters) 
{        

    return return preg_match('@/^(?!0\d|0' . $parameters[0] .'$)\d+(?:\.\d+)?' . $parameters[0] . '$/@', $value);    
}



protected function validateCheckWeight($attribute, $value, $parameters) 
{   
    dd('@/^(?!0\d|0' . $parameters[0] .'$)\d+(?:\.\d+)?' . $parameters[0] . '$/@');
    // output "@/^(?!0\d|0kg$)\d+(?:\.\d+)?kg$/@"
    return preg_match('@/^(?!0\d|0' . $parameters[0] .'$)\d+(?:\.\d+)?' . $parameters[0] . '$/@', $value);
    // this always outputs false

}
```

Comment: What *exactly* does "doesn't work" mean? You need to supply a test case. What values are you passing in for `$attribute`, `$value` and `$parameters`, and what return value are you expecting?

Comment: BTW: It looks like the `$attribute` argument is never used.

Comment: it returns true of false and $parameters[0] is the weight type e.g. kg or lbs

Comment: And what are you passing in for `$value`?

Comment: value being passed in is 12kg

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 different delimiters in your regex, `@` and `/`. I've just confirmed that if you remove `@` from the beginning and end of your regular expression, your function returns true for the inputs mentioned in your comments (`$value` = `"kg"`, `$parameters` = `array('kg')`).

Comment: Thank you that was the problem I learned something new today cheers

Answer (score 0):

If I correct understand this question you can

```
return strlen(parameters[0]) == strlen(rtrim(parameters[0],'lb'));
```

but I think again don't correct understand this.